# How to I get the specific item inside an array inside a collection of Users created with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
// database: db.getCollection('users').find({})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60af81e943d991265c2b8746"),
    "email" : "test@gmail.com.com",
    "password" : "123456",
    "notes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60af81e943d991265c2b8747"),
            "title" : "test title",
            "content" : "test content"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

// userSchema

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  notes: [{ title: String, content: String }],
});
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
app.post("/save", function (req, res) {

  const idNote = req.body._id;

  const userID = req.user._id;

  User.findById({ _id: userID }, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const notesArray = foundUser.notes;
     }
    }

      console.log(notesArray);
    })
  });
```

Now, is there a way to to get the specific (notes._id inside user._id) and use it to query the document(so i can find the specific "note" inside an user) or the only way the query works is looking for a collection where the only props that ca be used to query the document are the ones inside of schema?

If I am right then...

```
const newTitle = req.body.title;
const newContent = req.body.content;
const userID = req.user._id;

User.findById({ _id: userID }, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      const notesArray = foundUser.notes;

      const note = findNote(editNote, notesArray);

      function findNote(editNote, notesArray) {
        for (let i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
          if (notesArray[i]._id == editNote) {
            return notesArray[i];
          } else {
            console.log("not found!");
          }
        }
      }

      console.log(note);

    }
  });
```

How can I delete the "note" that I need to edit, and then create a NEW ONE + ALL the rest of the array and ending up with pushing the new array of notes to the schema prop "notes":[],

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60af81e943d991265c2b8746"),
    "email" : "test@gmail.com.com",
    "password" : "123456",
    "notes" : --> HERE <--,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to add/delete/edit `note` object in `notes` array of the specific user property. You can do any of these with just one query.

**Add new item**

If you want to add new item to `notes` array for a specific user, you can do it with `$push` operator, like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "user_1"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "notes": {
      "_id": "note_5",
      "title": "test title",
      "content": "test content"
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AvRjSKZxNt7

**Delete item**

If you want to delete item from `notes` array for a specific user, you can do it with `$pull` operator, like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "user_1"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "notes": {
      "_id": "note_4" 
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/M_gS2T00PDS

**Edit item**

If you want to edit item from `notes` array for a specific user, you can do it with
[positional "$" operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "user_1",
  "notes._id": "note_4"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "notes.$.title": "This is new title"
  }
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gn9R5u2rBJd